# How to find the image coordinate (x,y,width,height) every time when applying UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I have an `UIImage`, when I applying `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` the size of image becomes increase and decrease these are working fine, but I want to find the image coordinate eg.(x, y, width, height) every time when I am using `UIPinchGesture`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using image in a `UIImageView` class. You can get the co-ordinates and height, width from the frame property of `UIImageView`. So just get it from `yourUIImageViewObject.frame`

Hope its clear.

Comment: Thanks for answering me: can u give me some code for getting height and width of image.

Comment: There is a property named "size" in UIImage class. You can use that to get the height and widht of the image.